# Commutation of $c_0$-semigroups

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Task is: given two $c_0$-semigroups $T(t)$ and $S(t)$ in Banach space X with property $\forall \;t \geq 0 : T(t)S(t) = S(t)T(t)$, show that
$\forall \; t, s \geq 0 : T(t)S(s) = S(s)T(t)$.

I've tried using some addition-subtraction tricks and differentiating
$\varphi(t,s) = T(t)S(s)x - S(s)T(t)x$ (defined for arbitrary $x \in X$), but none of these methods succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Fix $t \in (0,\infty)$ and set
$$
  A := \{s \in [0,\infty): T(t)S(s) = S(s)T(t)\}.
$$
Show that if $s \in A$ and $k \in \mathbb{N} := \{1,2,\dots\}$, then $ks \in A$ and $s/k \in A$, too.

Comment: Thanks for hint! I’d like to add a brief solution. It was easier for me to give a geometric interpretation. Consider quarter plane $\{t\geq 0, s \geq 0 \}$. From the task, operators commute only on the line $t=s$. It’s easy to show that for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ $T(t) S(n t) = S(n t) T(t)$ and $T(m s) S(s) = S(s) T(m s)$, so we get commutation on lines $t=k s$ and $t=s/k$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}$). Hence, operators also commute for $s=q t$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ — it’s dense subset of quarter plane. This, they commute for all $t, s \geq 0$.